# Why this template specification doesn't work for reference?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code, where I have a template specification for a reference to structure. It seems that the function doesn't recognize that specification and continue use the original template definition.

If I get rid of the `&` operators in the template specification, I get a worked program.

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
T larger(T a, T b);

struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

template <> point& larger(point & p1, point & p2);

int main()
{   
    using namespace std;
    point p1 = { 1.1, 2.2 };
    point p2 = { 3.3, 4.4 };
    point &q1 = p1; // this is already a reference to 'point'
    point &q2 = p2;
    point q3 = larger(q1, q2);  // neither this
    point q4 = larger(p1, p2);  // nor this works

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}

template <typename T>
T larger(T a, T b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}


template <> point& larger(point& p1, point& p2) 
{
    return p1.x*p1.y > p2.x * p2.y ? p1 : p2;
}
```

Comment: When the compiler substitutes template parameters, it does some transformations on the type so that in this case `T` would never be deduced to be a reference. I'm guessing that because of that the specialization will never be a match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) is a complex thing, between qualifiers, references, etc. You can easily get lost.

What you can do here is to define your template function as taking universal references:

```
struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

template <typename T>
T larger(T&& a, T&& b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

template<> point& larger(point& p1, point& p2) 
{
    return p1.x*p1.y > p2.x * p2.y ? p1 : p2;
}

int main()
{   
    point p = { 1.1, 2.2 };
    point& rp = p;
    point max = larger(rp, rp); // deduced: point& larger<point&>(point&, point&)
}
```

demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78441512a5fa85aa

---

Or you can avoid Template argument deduction altogether:

```
template <typename T>
T larger(T a, T b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
// ...
point max = larger<point&>(rp, rp);
```

Comment: what is (void)max used to do?

Comment: Silence "unused variable" errors ^^ I've removed it as it could be misleading.

Comment: The explicit initialization seems to be a better solution, for if I change the the `point` structure to a buildin-type such as `int`, the universal deduction will give an error: more than one instance of overload function.

Comment: @buzhidao "explicit instantiation" ;)

Comment: @buzhidao BTW, have you thought of using `std::max` in conjunction with defining `bool operator<(point const&, point const&)`? This is the idiomatic way.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just doing a practice and want to figure out the problem;)